# How do I roll back from today's update to 8.0?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, update

I've only had the update for an hour. 
I HATE it!!!
nothing is where it's supposed to be. 
I cant get text instead of icons. I can barely SEE icons. 
classic theme restorer does not work and system restore did not fix it.
there is no uninstall file in the folder - my theme is broken.. everything is green.. the tabs are way too big.
I hate it so much I had to come here with palemoon.
Please tell me how to roll back
I really don't want to have to reinstall windows to remove all traces of this update.
Deleting all TOR folders and reinstalling an older version and disabling the update feature doe NOT work.
Every time I close the older version, it updates anyway
If someone has a way to roll back.. or which version to roll back to so it doesn't keep putting the latest update on my machine.. please.. enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/7.5.6/ 
when you first start in the settings, you can disable checking for updates

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete 8.0
2. Reinstall 7.5.6
3. Do NOT launch TOR
4. Go to the directory where TOR is installed (browser, TOR, etc)
5. Cut updater.exe from directory
6. Rename updater.exe to something like updaterexe.old
7. Is the only way to prevent auto updates from occurring

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to downgrade my Tor browser recently, but I had to do some searching to find the installation files for that version. I found the following options for that.

If it's a very recent version you can probably find it at  https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/

If it is an older version, you can probably find it in the package archive. https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/